# Getting error while I'm try to use Angular CLI with @ngrx

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ngrx

My Ng, Npm, NodeJs configuration is:

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.2
Node: 10.12.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 7.0.0
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, material, material-moment-adapter
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.10.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.10.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.10.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.10.2
@angular-devkit/core              7.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cli                      7.0.2
@ngtools/webpack                  7.0.2
@schematics/angular               7.0.2
@schematics/update                0.10.2
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.3
webpack                           4.19.1
```

And what I'm trying to run is:

```
ng g store AppState --root --module app.module.ts
```

getting the following error

```
Cannot read property 'entries' of undefined
```

UPDATE

I was able to create a store, but not an action:

```
➜  angular-ngrx-course git:(1-auth) ✗ ng g store AppStore --root --modiule app.module.ts
CREATE src/app/reducers/index.ts (359 bytes)
➜  angular-ngrx-course git:(1-auth) ✗ ng g action auth/Auth
Cannot read property 'entries' of undefined
➜  angular-ngrx-course git:(1-auth) ✗
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorted it changing a version of **@angular-devkit/schematics** from **0.6.x** to **^7.0.0**